# How can i query the undoInfo in a python string in maya?

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I'm developing a tool for maya and would like to query the undo history in a python string to process it.
I've found that `undoInfo( q=True, pq=True )` displays the undo history in maya's script console, but doesn't return anything so i can't store this result in a variable.

Is there another command to get this information, and if not, is there a way for me to get the result displayed in maya's console?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the cleanest method, but you can use [scriptEditorInfo](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/scriptEditorInfo.html) to write the undoInfo output to a temporary file like so:

```
pm.scriptEditorInfo(historyFilename="/tmp/undoInfoRecord.txt", writeHistory=True)
pm.undoInfo(q=True, pq=True)
pm.scriptEditorInfo(writeHistory=False)

undoInfoLines = []
with open('/tmp/undoInfoRecord.txt') as f:
    undoInfoLines = f.readlines()
undoInfoLines = undoInfoLines[2:-1]  # Remove scriptEditorInfo outputs and undoInfo command
```

Comment: Works fine! Had to remove `undoInfoLines = undoInfoLines[2:-1]` cause there didn't seem to be any outputs from scriptEditorInfo, nor the undoInfo command in the temporary file. Thanks you :)